# Background-size ; strange behaviour on Safari 9

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, background-size

I'm working on this website: http://novoayaburto.cl

The main hero background image works fine on every browser (also mobile) **except for a bug on the Safari 9 browser running on Mac OSX 10.11**.

Here's a screen capture of the bug on Safari:

[image: broken background position on Safari 9]

I'm using background-size: cover to produce the expected behaviour displayed on every other browser (except Safari, which shows a broken image).

Why is this only happening on Safari?
How would I be able to fix this?

Comment: show your html and css code

Comment: yes, i also suspect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inspect your website, In safari `transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)` is missing. Thats why its causing the half image problem.

After I put this CSS style, I see the full-size hero image in safari.

[image: Here the safari browser view]